# How can I fix my mic from playing static?

Tags: 16.04, alsa, microphone

The internal speakers serve as primary audio output. The mic picks up a low level of static constantly, but not my voice. The mic could have been compromised at some point, I'm not ruling this out, but I've seen enough similar issues with audio in Ubuntu so I'm exploring the possibility that it is not hardware failure.

I've tried adding:

```
options snd-hda-intel id=PCH,HDMI index=0,1
```

To the config file here:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

But when I reboot and run alsamixer the default is still HDMI.

Any thoughts, suggestions, resources, thanks.

[image: Alsamixer]

[image: Mic showing static]

Answer (score 3):

It's not a Bash command. It's an ALSA option. You have to edit your `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file:

```
nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Probably `sudo` will be necessary.